# Concurrent page scraping with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I make [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) follow multiple links in new page instances, to evaluate them in a concurrent and asynchronous way?

Comment: What did you try till now? What worked and what's not working?

Answer (score 11):

Mareks solution is fine for a few pages, but in case you want to crawl a large number of pages concurrently, I recommend looking at my library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster).

It runs tasks in parallel (like Mareks solution), but also takes care of error handling, retrying and some other things. You can see a minimal example below. It's also possible to use the library in more complex settings.

```js
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

(async () => {
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT, // use one browser per worker
    maxConcurrency: 4, // cluster with four workers
  });

  // Define a task to be executed for your data
  await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    await page.goto(url);
    const screen = await page.screenshot();
    // ...
  });

  // Queue URLs
  cluster.queue('http://www.google.com/');
  cluster.queue('http://www.wikipedia.org/');
  // ...

  // Wait for cluster to idle and close it
  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
})();
```

Comment: How would you add a simple proxy switcher for cases where running browsers in concurrency and parsing single domain would potentially cause requests getting blocked? If you have a sample snippet example that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Almost every Puppeteer method returns a `Promise`. So you can use for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool package.

First you need create an async function that processes one url:

```
const crawlUrl = async (url) => {
    // Open new tab.
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    // Evaluate code in a context of page and get your data.
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
            title: document.title,
            url: window.location.href,
        };
    });
    results.push(result);

    // Close it.
    await page.close();
};
```

Then you need promise producer. Every time this function is called it takes one url from `URLS_TO_BE_CRAWLED` constant and returns `crawlUrl(url)` promise. Once `URLS_TO_BE_CRAWLED` gets empty it returns `null` instead which finishes the pool.

```
const promiseProducer = () => {
    const url = URLS_TO_BE_CRAWLED.pop();

    return url ? crawlUrl(url) : null;
};
```

Finally you executes this with CONCURRENCY of your choice:

```
const pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer, CONCURRENCY);
await pool.start();
```

Since this is very often asked question I also made a working example at our Apify platform https://www.apify.com/mtrunkat/puppeteer-promise-pool-example

---

EDIT 12.10.2018

I would also add that we have recently build whole open source SDK around concurrent scraping with Puppeteer. It solves the main pains such as:

- autoscaling concurrency based on CPU and memory
- failed request retries using request queue
- rotation of browsers (to switch proxies)

Check it out at: https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js